# PowerShell Input Validation - Input should NOT be ALL numbers

Tags: validation, input

I have the following code that works well for validating length...

```
DO {
    $NewID = Read-Host -Prompt " NEW ID NAME of object (8-15 chars)   "
} UNTIL ($NewID.Length -gt 7 -and $WS_NewName.Length -lt 16)
```

How can I include code that ensures input contains either an ALPHA or ALPHANUMERIC string, but NOT a purely NUMERIC one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily doable using regular expressions like that:

```
($NewID -match '^[A-z0-9]*$') -and ($NewID -notmatch '^[0-9]*$')
```

Short explanation: first expression looks for alpha/alphanumeric string and the second discards purely numeric entries.

By the way, in your example you use `$NewID` and then `$WS_NewName` in `Until` expression, that might be confusing (however, I assume you just forgot to change it while pasting here)

Comment: Yes, you're right about the variable, @robdy.  I overlooked that, sorry.  And thanks for the concise explanation to the answer you provided.  Made me understand the use and structure or regex better. =)